# MySQL, CONCAT in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

```
(SELECT CONCAT(@I, '_Delta') FROM table WHERE id_tb = @ID)
```

I'm using the above statement as part of an INSERT. The problem is the whole line is being translated to the value of `@I` (this is an index, values are i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...). So, instead of getting the output of the SELECT I'm getting 0, 1, 2, ...

The expected value of the CONCAT is like `"0_Delta"`, then `"1_Delta"`, etc. Replacing the CONCAT by one of this works.

Any comments will be appreciated. Thanks!

[code]

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xxx_tb;
CREATE TABLE xxx_tb
(
    i_Validity INT,
    Delta INT
);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS AFTER_INSERT_ON_tb_in;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER_INSERT_ON_tb_in 
    AFTER INSERT ON tb_in 
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

```
SET @ID = NEW.id_tb;
SET @TYPE = (SELECT Type FROM header WHERE id_tb = @ID);


IF @TYPE = 'abcd' THEN

    SET @SAMPLES = (SELECT SampleNumber FROM table WHERE id_tb = @ID);

    IF(@SAMPLES > 1) THEN
        SET @I = 0;
        WHILE(@I < @SAMPLES) DO

            INSERT INTO xxx_tb
            (
                i_Validity, 
                Delta
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                (SELECT 0_Validity FROM table WHERE id_tb = @ID), 
                (SELECT CONCAT(@I, '_Delta') FROM table WHERE id_tb = @ID)
            );
            SET @I = @I + 1;

        END WHILE;

    END IF;

END IF;


END$$
```

DELIMITER ;
[code]

Comment: Please show the whole `INSERT` query.

Comment: and the fields in the table

Comment: I agree. If you have it in parens, it won't output the rows of the select and instead prepares it for use in a larger statement. Try without parens or show full statement.

Comment: Garr Godfrey, please, which parens are you referring to? This (
                i_Validity, 
                Delta
            )?

Answer (score 0):

`delta` is declared as an integer.  You are getting a silent conversion from the string value.  Because `@i` is at the beginning, that is the value you are getting.

You can try declaring it as `varchar(255)` if you want a string value.

Your `insert` can be written more easily as an `insert . . . select`:

```
    INSERT INTO xxx_tb(i_Validity, Delta) 
        SELECT `0_Validity`, CONCAT(@I, '_Delta')
        FROM table WHERE id_tb = @ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy INSERT! Please, could you give some more words about this silent conversion? You mean the CONCAT is ok but the output from the SELECT is being converted silently?

Comment: You are assigning a string value to an integer.  The string gets converted to an integer, by converting initial digits to a number.